# JSON_EACH Columns

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have the following code

```
   SELECT 

 p1.json_data -> 'factSheet'->'fact_sheet' ->'cash_flow' AS Date

 FROM loan_applications AS l
 LEFT JOIN risk_scores AS p1
 ON l.id = p1.loan_application_id
 WHERE l.human_readable_id = 'XXX'
```

And get this ouput:
{"21-01-11": 772.28, "21-01-12": 1210.28,...}

For my understanding, I should use json_each

```
 json_each(p1.json_data -> 'factSheet'->'fact_sheet' ->'cash_flow') AS Date
```

but that just gives me the following output:

(21-01-11,772.28) 
(21-01-12,1210.28) 
...
...

I basically want the Date in one column and the revenue in the other.

Thanks

Comment: json_each needs to be in the FROM list, not the SELECT list.

Comment: Works, thanks. I just have to figure out how to join, but that shouldn't be a problem